# jhipster production build angular code different from local

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm using jhipster for an application, and I need file uploading capability. Angular does not have ng-change function for input type file, so I put in a regular onchange function, which goes like this:

```
onchange="angular.element($('#fileElem')).scope().vm.upload(this.files, angular.element($('#fileElem')).scope().vm)"
```

Now the problem is that when I run this function locally (by running gradlew command), it works. But when I run the same on the application deployed to heroku, it gives an error.

As part of my attempt to debug, I thought I'll try to find out what's different using javascript console, and I found that heroku version is not returning a scope. Indeed, the scope function contents are also different. On heroku, it is coming from generated.js, whereas locally it is coming from angular.js.

Attching two pictures which show how they are different.

Working version on local:
[image]

Non-Working version on heroku:
[image]

Where do I begin to resolve this? I this a gulp issue where it is packaging the angular file incorrectly, into a generated.js bundle?